# Power Supply - RPI and a Load

Tags: pcb, current, circuit-design, raspberry-pi

I'm building a project that involves a raspberry and a small 3-6v water pump.
As the RPI and the water pump run on 5V I am using a single 110v-5v 2.5 Amp walwart to supply the power.

My question is, will I cause the raspberry pi harm as a variable current passes through the load? Initially the raspberry pi was not a happy but upon adding a flyback diode it seems to be OK. Are there other precautions I should take to ensure the RPI is not harmed?

[image: snip]

Comment: I would change the diode from a zener to a standard diode with a forward .7V drop as opposed to the higher drop of the zener. Also a .1uF or a little higher, also across the motor, (motors are noisy) will clean up your power line.   Both components should be as close to the motor as possible as good practice dictates.

Comment: (Sorry about the duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the diode from a zener to a standard diode with a forward .7V drop as opposed to the higher drop of the zener. Also a .1uF or a little higher, also across the motor, (motors are noisy) will clean up your power line. Both components should be as close to the motor as possible as good practice dictates.